# How to load multiple documents in WebView from URL (PDFTron)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdftron

I am trying to use PDFTron to load several documents and then open them dynamically onClick event. The trouble is I can't access the instance object from outside the return of the WebViewer promise - I need to create dynamic buttons that load a document depending on the button that I click. They are not going to be hardcoded so I can't load in documents from fixed URL's for each button.

Here is the example code from PDFTron. Mine is nearly identical - the only difference is I need the loadDocumentButtons to be dynamic. I don't know a way to do this due to scoping issues; the instance object is trapped within the return of the promise and I don't know how to access it from outside the promise return. Can anyone help with this?

```
WebViewer({
  ...
}, viewerElement)
  .then(instance => {
    loadDocumentButton.on('click', () => {
      instance.loadDocument('mysite.com/myDocument.pdf', { documentId: 'id2' });
    });

    loadAnotherDocumentButton.on('click', () => {
      instance.loadDocument('mysite.com/myOtherDocument.pdf', { documentId: 'id2' });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different approaches you could take. The first is to use a config file, which is basically a javascript file that gets executed in the context of the iframe in which WebViewer is run. Example:

```
WebViewer({
  initialDoc: "mydoc.pdf",
  config: "path/to/my/config/file.js" // relative to your HTML file
}, viewerElement);
```

Inside the config file you will have access to the Document, DocumentViewer and AnnotationManager objects (among others).
[Config Files](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/config-files/)

You can also call the [getInstance](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/global.html#getInstance) API, which returns an existing instance of WebViewer.

```
import { getInstance } from '@pdftron/webviewer'

// After WebViewer has already been constructed
const instance = getInstance();
```